# Creating a temporary secret storage in Jenkins for the current build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I cant keep my credentials in the Jenkins, i't company policy. But i can take credentials in the external storage.
How creating a temporary secret storage in Jenkins for the **current build** so that I can use plugins?

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.Domain
import com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsScope

instance = Jenkins.instance
domain = Domain.global()
store = instance.getExtensionList(
  "com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider")[0].getStore()

privateKey = new BasicSSHUserPrivateKey.DirectEntryPrivateKeySource(
  '''
PRIVATE_KEY_TEXT
  '''
)

sshKey = new BasicSSHUserPrivateKey(
  CredentialsScope.USER,
  "SECRET_TEXT",
  "PRIVATE_KEY_USERNAME",
  privateKey,
  "PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE",
  "SECRET_DESCRIPTION"
)

// sshKey will be save in the storage Jenkins :(
store.addCredentials(domain, sshKey)
```

I try to create a `def scp = new SystemCredentialsProvider` and `scp.addCredentials(domain, sshKey)` but when I try to use `withCredentials(... credetialsId: 'PRIVATE_KEY_USERNAME')` I get an error, credentials dont found.

Answer (score 0):

The private key file is usually stored in `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa` (Win) or `~/.ssh/id_rsa` (*nix) and only the specific user has access to it (apart from Administrator/`root`). Copy it to a folder in the user's folder that's not hidden (otherwise it can't be selected at *File* <kbd>Browse...</kbd> below) and:

- ***Manage Jenkins*** → ***Manage Credentials*** → select your *Store*/*Add domain* → select your *Domain* → *Add Credentials* → *Kind*: *Secret file* →  *File* <kbd>Browse...</kbd>

Comment: I cannot do this since I am not an administrator. This is forbidden by politic company. I can only create a task / library and run. And I want to understand if it is possible to create a secret without saving it. Because when you execute store.addCredentials (domain, sshKey) it will save it to the server. Maybe there are alternative ways

Comment: @Tema054 Then ask an admin to do that together with you. If that's forbidden either, change the company.